# ASP.NET MVC website with npm, webpack and angular2?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, node.js, asp.net-mvc

With the advent of all of these javascript module loaders, I am trying to understand the configuration I need to set up Angular 2 in my ASP.NET MVC web application with Webpack. Here is what I *know* (subject to correction) so far:

- Webpack is a module loader. So it will be able to bundle up my entire Angular 2 application by pointing the `webpack.config.js` file to my angular app and have it output a single file I can import into my HTML
- npm gives me the ability to manage all of my Angular 2 components in a `package.json` file, which will stick all of the dependencies for Angular 2 in subfiles/folders under `node_modules`

I've already run through and downloaded things such as `Typescript` into Visual Studio, and I have `node` and `npm` installed. The `Task Runner Explorer` has also picked up the `webpack.config.js` file and I can run it and see a built javascript file. Here is my basic file structure (minus irrelevant folders/files)

```
Solution
    node_modules
        @angular
        core-js
        es6-shim
        rxjs
        reflect-metadata
        ...
    Scripts
        app
            component-1
            component-2
            ...
        shared
            directives
            interfaces
            services
            ...
        app.component.ts <-- Should have the root level angular 2 component
        main.ts <-- should be entry point into angular 2 application
    Scripts-Build
        main.bundle.js <-- Webpack places my bundled js file here
    package.json
    webpack.config.js
```

My `package.json` file looks like this

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "aspnet",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^2.4.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.5",
        "@angular/core": "^2.4.5",
        "@angular/forms": "^2.4.5",
        "@angular/http": "^2.4.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.5",
        "@angular/router": "^3.4.5",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "rxjs": "5.0.1",
        "systemjs": "0.19.40",
        "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
    }
}
```

My `webpack.config.js` file looks like this

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "Scripts"),
    entry: "./main.ts",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "Scripts-Build"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    }
}
```

---

**The hiccup**

The hiccup I am having is when I try writing a hello-world style application for Angular 2, I am having trouble importing the modules from my `node_modules` folder. Here is what `app.component.ts` looks like

```
import { Component } from "../../node_modules/@angular/core/index.js"
```

**The error I am seeing is Cannot use imports, exports, or module augmentations when '--module' is 'none'**

Am I doing something terribly wrong or am I missing a subtlety here?

Comment: Built the same environment a few weeks ago with MVC Core (not sure for your version?): Take a look at this link : http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/ you can create a new project with this and check what could be missing in yours.

Answer (score 0):

*This will be updated as I find out what I need to do to fix this issue*

1. Run `npm install @types/es6-shim --save-dev` (fixes missing `Promise`, `Map` and `Set` types when building solution)
2. Change the import statement to `import { Component } from "../../node_modules/@angular/core"` (fixes path to import from `node_modules`)
3. Add a `tsconfig.js` file the root of the solution with the following contents

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "noImplicitAny": false,
           "noEmitOnError": true,
           "removeComments": false,
           "sourceMap": true,
           "target": "es5",
           "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
           "experimentalDecorators": true,
           "moduleResolution": "node"
       },
       "include": [
           "Scripts"
       ],
       "exclude": [
           "node_modules",
           "wwwroot"
       ]
   }
   ```

1/29/2017 edit, I think I will need https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader for webpack to load the typescript files..